# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'UserDto' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, illegalstateexception

**Http Page**

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: An exception occurred processing [WEB-INF/layout/baseLayout.jsp] at line [28]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: An exception occurred processing [WEB-INF/layout/baseLayout.jsp] at line [28]

25:     </tr>   
26:     
27:     <tr>
28:       <td><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
29:       </td>
30:     </tr>
31:     


Stacktrace:
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: An exception occurred processing [WEB-INF/layout/baseLayout.jsp] at line [28]

25:     </tr>   
26:     
27:     <tr>
28:       <td><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
29:       </td>
30:     </tr>
31:
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://tilles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

 <!-- scenario 1 -->


<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="baseTemplate" id="baseTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/layout/baseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layout/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/layout/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="${body}" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>
  
  <definition name="login" id="login" extends="baseTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />
  </definition>
  
  <definition name="regis" id="regis" extends="baseTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/registration.jsp" />
  </definition>
  
  </tiles-definitions>
```

**registration.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>


<html>
<body>
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="UserDto"
        action="submitRegis.do">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>name <form:input path="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>age <form:input path="age" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>email <form:input path="email" />
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>password <form:password path="password" />
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>


                <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>

            </tr>


        </table>


    </form:form>


</body>
</html>
```

**RegistrationController**

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationControl {
    @RequestMapping("/registering")
    public String showRegistrationPage(Map<String, Object>map) {
        System.out.println("Inside Registration Control");
        
        UserDto usr=new UserDto();
        
        map.put("userDto", usr);
        
        return "regis";
        
    }
```

**UserDto.java **

```
package com.pp.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_dto")

public class UserDto {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    String email;

    @Column
    String password;

    @Column
    String name;

    @Column
    String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

In the same project I have login page also but it seems to work fine, it has not gone through any bindingexceptions till. When I am just passing message in registration page instead of attributes, it's working.

I am not using model attribute as I only want it for now on my Html page.

Answer (score 0):

In `registration.jsp` `modelAttribute` is `UserDto`, whereas in `RegistrationController` in `map.put("userDto", usr);` the key is `userDto`. That's why it was unable to bind.

ModelAttribute and Key should match with one another.

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationControl {
    @RequestMapping("/registering")
    public String showRegistrationPage(Map<String, Object>map) {

        System.out.println("Inside Registration Control");
        UserDto usr=new UserDto();
        map.put("UserDto", usr);
        return "regis";
    }
```

Now it is working fine.